# Why does the compiler gives an error (abort trap: 6) when using the ?? operator on a dictionary

Tags: swift, llvm

This is my code:

```
func x() {
    var y = [String: [Int]]()
    y["crash"]?.append(1) ?? y["crash"] == [1]
}
```

Why does this instantly gives an error from the compiler? `y["crash"]?.append(1)` has the return type of `()?` while `y["crash"] == [1]` has a return type of `()`, therefore my code looks valid at first sight.

Comment: "therefore my code looks valid at first sight." No it doesn't! Your code makes no sense whatever. On the other hand, the compiler should not crash. On the other other hand, I can't reproduce any crash. I get a compile error, "Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred". Make sure you're using the latest Xcode.

Comment: @matt A I see... I had the toolchain of 30 november. When running the toolchain of today, it doesn't crash anymore. That toolchain gives an other error: Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '()?' and '[Int]?'.

Comment: If you get a compiler crash on a current experimental toolchain, report it immediately! This is exactly why toolchains are released early. — And when asking a question involving a toolchain, always say so explicitly. — By the way, the new compiler error message you now report is excellent, so clearly they’ve worked on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`, doesn't makes much sense following `append`, a method that doesn't return anything. The general pattern with `nil` coalescing operator is:

```
let foo = bar() ?? "baz"
```

That sets `foo` to the value returned by `bar()`, unless that method returned `nil`, in which case `foo` would be set the to value `"baz"`.

The correct syntax in Swift 4 to achieve the desired behavior is to use the `default` parameter:

```
var y = [String: [Int]]()
y["nocrash", default: []].append(1)
```

---

Technically, in the interest of full disclosure, you theoretically can use the `nil`-coalescing operator as you've outlined. The operator `a ?? b` evaluates to `a != nil ? a! : b`.

Thus, with judicious use of parentheses and replacing your `==` with `=`, you could do (though I would never recommend it) something like the following:

```
y["crash"]?.append(0) ?? (y["crash"] = [0])
```

But, this is an anti-pattern, something to be avoided. Use the `default` syntax, above.

The typical pattern of `nil`-coalescing operator is as follows:

```
let c = a ?? b
```

where `a` is optional. If `a` is not `nil`, `c` will be assigned the value of `a`, otherwise it will be assigned the value of `b`.

Comment: And before Swift 4 I think we had to say something like `y["crash"] = y["crash"] == nil ? [1] : y["crash"]!+[1]`

Comment: Yep. Or just use `if`-`else`. Lots of ways of doing it. But not `nil` coalescing operator. ;)

Comment: DIdn't know about the default initializer for accessing a dictionary, thanks :)